# Sending commands to server using Poco library

Tags: c++, sockets, poco-libraries

I'm new to socket programming. I'm working with the Poco library. I found this example online. (https://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf)

```
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketStream.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("www.appinf.com", 80);
Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket(sa)
Poco::Net::SocketStream str(socket);
str << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
 "Host: www.appinf.com\r\n"
 "\r\n";
str.flush();
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(str, std::cout);
return 0;
}
```

I understand that a socket stream is created. 
I cannot understand the commands. What does the "/" do after "GET" or what is "1.1". Please do explain what that particular line means.
This code does give me an output. But how do the commands work? And is there a way to give the commands from the console? Thanks.

Comment: See [https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

Comment: The contents of the message sent to the server are specific to what the server expects to receive.  If you were connected to a mail server the content would be different because they would conform to the SMTP protocol, but this specific content is how you talk to a web server that accepts version 1.1 of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do here.

Are you trying to do HTTP or not?

If not, then do your own text, but don't use port **80** as that is the well known **http** port.

If you want to just send whatever you type over a TCP socket, then you probably could use the `StreamCopier` to send everything from `std::cin` to `str`.